# NodeJS "Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Tags: javascript, node.js

> Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
>   Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

My local NodeJS setup becomes intermittently becomes unresponsive . When I refresh my computer it works fine but it keeps giving me the following message. Does anything in my code scream **WRONG**.

```
//dependencies

var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var schemas = require('./schemas/schemas');

    //main config 
    var app = express();
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.set('view options', {
       layout: false
    });
    app.use(express.logger());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.cookieParser('BodySnatchingLizardPPL'));
    app.use(express.session());
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());

    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    app.configure('development', function () {
       app.use(express.errorHandler({
          dumpExceptions: true,
          showStack: true
       }));
    });

    app.configure('production', function () {
       app.use(express.errorHandler());
    });

    //passport config
    var Account = require('./models/account');
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(Account.authenticate()));
    passport.serializeUser(Account.serializeUser());
    passport.deserializeUser(Account.deserializeUser());


    //mongoose
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://demo2:demo2@ds033699.mongolab.com:33699/nicksdbthing');


    require("fs").readdirSync("./routes_data_get/").forEach(function(file) {
      require("./routes_data_get/" + file)(app);
    });

    require("fs").readdirSync("./routes_data_post/").forEach(function(file) {
      require("./routes_data_post/" + file)(app);
    });

    require("fs").readdirSync("./routes_data_post/").forEach(function(file) {
      require("./routes_data_post/" + file)(app);
    });



    app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
       console.log(("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port')))
    });
```

Comment: The problem would likely be with one of your routes in `./routes_data_get/`. Also, you shouldn't be defining your cookieParser secret in code (use an environment variable).